# Batch_Job_Execution_Context serialized_context field

Tags: spring, spring-batch

How should I decide on the max size of the CLOB fields in the tables `Batch_Job_Execution_Context` and `Batch_Step_Execution_Context`. Do we need to set this as 4GB always. How do we estimate the max size of this for my project? What is the recommended practice?

Comment: You can estimate like, how many time you kick off the job per day/month/year. You also can try start a job and see how much storage occupied by Spring batch tables, ask DBA for information. Base on the information, we can see what size we should setup for Spring Batch tables.

Comment: I was interested to know more on the Serialized_context column and the size that we should set for these two columns in the table. How does this get used, is this used only at the time when a job fails and restarts  or this is used everytime when a job runs

Comment: When you store anything to JobExecutionContext or StepExecutionContext, those fields will have data. You can see an example here https://bigzidane.wordpress.com/2016/09/12/spring-batch-partitionerreaderprocesorwriterhibernateintellij/ and see Partitioner level  to see how we store to StepExecutionContext.

Comment: Does it get used when job restarts

Comment: Yes it does use it